# App Store Broken Download Xcode (Mac Os X Mountain Lion) Debug, Reset doesnt help!

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode

I started download Xcode 4 within App Store, it made some 200MB, then I had to move and closed my MBP.

Afterwards it didnt restart the download and I was getting nervous clicking around.

End of story: App Store shows Xcode as "ready to install" (which is aboslutely impossible since there have been over 1G still to be loaded with not a too good broad band connection)

Clicking on install just yield and endless "wait.."

I also used the Debug view to "Reset Applications" - still shows as "ready to install"

Under /Applications there is no install X Code folder to delete

Viewing the download folder (from debug view) there is also nothing to delete

**So the question is: how the hell am I supposed to fix this broken download?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Xcode shows directly as "Xcode.app" in /Applications.
Is there anything there ?

I deleted the (full) app from my /Applications folder, relaunched App Store and it was possible to click on "Install" again.

Comment: NOPE:  `ls /Applications/`  
App Store.app  Contacts.app  FaceTime.app  Google Chrome.app Messages.app  QuickTime Player.app System Preferences.app iMovie.app
Automator.app  DVD Player.app  FileZilla.app  Hotspot Shield.app Mission Control.app Reminders.app  TextEdit.app  iPhoto.app
Calculator.app  Dashboard.app  Font Book.app  Image Capture.app Notes.app  Safari.app  Time Machine.app iTunes.app
Calendar.app  Dictionary.app  Game Center.app  Launchpad.app  Photo Booth.app  Skype.app  Utilities  iWeb.app
Chess.app  Dropbox.app  GarageBand.app  Mail.app  Preview.app  Stickies.app  iDVD.app

Comment: There is a com.apple.appstore folder in ~/Library/Caches. Could you delete it once the App Store app is closed, log out and log back in ?

Comment: OK - somehow the damn internet config was broken in the hostle I am staying - going back to office network, the download just started from 0 KB again.

Thanks God, this horror has finally an end.